# API rate limit exceeded

Tags: github, cloud-automation-manager

I'm getting an error when trying to re-deploy a template for IBM Cloud, any idea?

> Error: API rate limit exceeded. Consider using an access token.

Comment: Its a public template.

Comment: Have you considered using an access token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it to work by using my own personal git access token for that template.

From the Cloud Automation Manager UI, under the "Template Source" tab, edit the "GitHub Access Token" and you can put in your own public github token to pull.